# Filter/Slice DropdownList based on another Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, drop-down-menu

Greetings and salutations, friends.

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the solution to a DropdownList problem:
**I'd like to filter/slice a dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist.**

The image below helps to illustrate what I want to do:

[image: Illustative Image]

Also: here's the code that populates the list.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Nome do cadastro:</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FinancialItems, new SelectList(Model.FinancialItems, "Description", "Description"),
               new { @id = "nomeCadastro", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

I'm using Javascript/JQuery, and C# with MVC5.
Is it possible to do this directly in JS/JQuery? (I could also use a plugin/API for this, if it exists!)

Thanks a million times!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, listening to the onChange event on first select you can generate dinamically the options for the second select.